# How to perform partial specialisation when two template parameters are of the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, specialization, partial-specialization

How to partial specialization that two template parameter are same type.

How to make this code using second function .

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename B>
void Translate(A&& a,B* b){
  // make some translate from a to b
  // b->bvalue=a.av;
  std::cout<<"normal function";
}
//if a and b are same type,
template <typename A>
void Translate(A&& a, A* b) {
  *b = std::forward<A>(a);
  std::cout<<"forward function";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int in=0,out=0;
  Translate(in,&out);
  return 0;
}
```

Expect out put  "forward function".

Comment: In the second overload `A` is being deduced as `int&` from the first parameter, and `int` from the second parameter, which makes it ambiguous and not viable.

Comment: Note that this is not partial specialization (you cannot partially specialize a function template), it's simply two different primary function template overloads of the `Translate` function. As PasserBy mentions, the first overload identified as a better match in overload resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the 2nd version can't be called at all. You're declaring the 1st parameter as [fowarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), when being passed an lvlaue `A` will be deduced as `T&`. Then for the 1st parameter `A` will be deduced as `int&`, for the 2nd parameter `A` will be deduced as `int`, they conflict.

You can use [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) for type adjustment. And to solve the following ambiguity issue you can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), to exclude undesired specializations from the overload set.

```
// if A and B are different types
template <typename A, typename B>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<A>, B>> Translate(A&& a,B* b){
  ...
}

// if they're the same type (as A) 
template <typename A>
void Translate(A&& a, std::remove_reference_t<A>* b) {
  ...
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XkrC0EqjMrYaRoSz)

BTW: Function templates can't be partial specialized; as your code showed they can only be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks.
`std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::remove_reference_t<A>, B>::value > Translate(A&& a,B* b)`  get right output.

Comment: Possibly worth explicitly pointing out, for readers not too familiar with `std::enable_if`, that we are relying here on the fact that its conditionally existing `::type` typedef defaults to `void`, and as these two overloads just so happens to be be `void` functions we can use `std::enable_if` to enable/disable an overload via its return type, instead of the most commonly seen approach of doing it via an additional template parameter.

Comment: If I except `template <>
void Translate<int,double>(int&& a,double* b){
  std::cout<<"double function"<<std::endl;
}`   then  `double double_out;  Translate(in,&double_out);` get  "double function"  output. How to implement?

Comment: @ZhigangZhang `int&& a` makes `a` an rvalue-reference, and `in` is an lvalue which can't be bound to `a`. You need to call it like `Translate(std::move(in),&double_out);`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an rvalue for the first parameter. Both of the following print "forward function".

```
Translate(0, &out);
// or
Translate(std::move(in), &out);
```

With `Translate(in, out)`, the second overload can't deduce the `A` type consistently: the first parameter is deduced as `int&` while second parameter is deduced as `int`.

```
main.cpp:12:6: note: candidate: 'template<class A> void Translate(A&&, A*)'
 void Translate(A&& a, A* b) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:19:21: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'A' ('int&' and 'int')
   Translate(in, &out);
```

So the compiler resorts to the first overload.